# chaining Option using orElse changed element type

Tags: scala

I find that after chaining Option using orElse, the element type changed, which made me impossible to use it as expected.

For example:an xml with the type of `NodeSeq`.

```
scala> xml1.headOption map { head => None } orElse xml2.lastOption map {last => Some(last)}
res11: Option[Some[ScalaObject with Equals]] = Some(Some(None))
```

before the `orElse`, `head` is of type `Node`, which is correct, but `last` should also be of type `Node`, but the compiler thinks it is of type `ScalaObject with Equals`, and i cannot pass `last` to functions take a `Node` as a parameter.

I can cast it using `last.asInstanceOf[Node]`, is there a way to avoid this cast and still make `last` of type `Node`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead (notice the added parenthesis):

```
(xml.headOption map { head => None }) orElse (xml.lastOption map {last => Some(last)})
```

The problem is that the `map` is being applied after `orElse` rather than before `orElse`. In other words, the expression is parsed like this:

```
((xml.headOption map { head => None }) orElse xml.lastOption) map {last => Some(last)}
```

Since the expression on the left-hand-side of `orElse` has type `Option[Option[Node]]` but the right-hand-side expression has type `Option[Node]` the lowest common supertype is `Option[ScalaObject with Equals]`.

Scala's flexible syntax can make coding very nice at times, but other times it results in crazy things like this. For complex expressions like this it's a good idea to add parenthesis to make your meaning more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think you need to re-examine what exactly you're doing, since it doesn't make much sense. `xml.headOption map { head => None }` is always going to resolve to `Some(None)` (in your case), which is rarely what you want. My best guess is that you want something like:

```
xml.headOption.orElse(xml.lastOption)
```

Though it's worth noting that if headOption is None, so will lastOption be.

Edit: As Dao Wen points out, it's quite possible to infer the correct upper bound of `Option[Node]` in this example, and the issue obscuring it was that of the wrong `orElse` being called. However, I still think that the real issue here is that what you're doing doesn't make much sense, and should probably be reconsidered.

Answer (score 0):

`map {head => None}` is probably not what you intend. It that a typo?

After that, you have an `Option[None.type]`, a not too interesting type which has only two possible values, `None` and `Some(None)`. 
As your xml is not empty, it happens to be Some(None).

`xml.LastOption` has type `Option[Node]`

So when you do the `orElse` bettwen them  it looks for the most precise common supertype (least upper bound), of `None.type` and `Node`. And there is none of interest, it happens to be `ScalaObject with Equals`, it could just as well be `AnyRef`.

Your final `map {last => Some(last)}` is rather strange too. What do you intend there?